# Laravel4: Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

The following code will throw an error

```
Call to a member function `links()` on a non-object
```

routes.php:

```
Route::get('videos', function(){
    $data = DB::table('video_data_r')->paginate(5);
    return View::make('video',$data);
});
```

Corresponding `video` view:

```
<?php foreach($data as $item): ?>
<div class="video_entry">
    <a href="<?php echo $item -> url; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $item -> thumb; ?>" /></a>
    <a href="<?php echo $item -> url; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $item -> title; ?>"</a>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php echo $data->links();?>
```

Could you give me a good hint on what looks like a trivial error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described [in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views) the second parameter to `View::make` should be an associative array of data to be exposed in the view as local scope variables.

So `$data = array('foo' => 'Ron', 'bar' => 'John);` would expose `$foo` and `$bar` to the view.

You are passing the result of `paginate` directly to the view, so it's keys will be exposed.

You should be passing `array('data' => $data)` instead.

Comment: Was saved. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

A more concise way would be using PHP [`compact`](http://php.net/compact) function

```
 return View::make('video',compact('data'));
```

Comment: Compact is a standard PHP function (http://php.net/compact), not Laravel defined.